# Rental listings are no longer attached to a User ID in MySQL

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I have a database with rentals with unique ID's for each rental, and each rental is linked to a user through a user ID. Essentially what happened is that people before me deleted the user before deleting their records, including rentals.

I tried joining user.id with it's associated rental.id where user.id is NULL, but it can't join on NULL user ID's. Here is an example MySQL query I ran (I changed the naming conventions to not match the database)

```
        SELECT user.email, user.id, user.name, rent.lastChanged, rent.id, rent.address
        FROM rental rent LEFT JOIN rentList ON rental.id = rentList.id
        RIGHT JOIN user ON user.id = rentList.id
        WHERE user.id NOT REGEXP '^-?[0-9]+$'
```

I tried joining where user is not a number (ie NULL), but no luck. Looking to also prevent this by putting parameters on the rentals to prevent this. Any insight on this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`null` is not a string. so you have to use `is null`

```
SELECT user.email, user.id, user.name, rent.lastChanged, rent.id, rent.address
        FROM rental rent LEFT JOIN rentList ON rental.id = rentList.id
        RIGHT JOIN user ON user.id = rentList.id
        WHERE user.id i null
```